# Redmine :Multiple repositories in a project

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Two questions actually

1) Have anyone accomplished setting up multiple repositories in a project or linking commits to repos across projects.

2) Issues referring to commit messages across projects and vice-verca

I was successful in hacking Redmine to link commit message in 'Repository' section of Redmine to refer to issue number in a different project but it doesn't appear in the 'Associated Revisions' part of the corresponding issue. Any ideas?

Any plug-in available to accomplish this?

Comment: Be interested to see the answer to this :-)

Comment: http://www.redmine.org/issues/779

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple repositories means that you have sub-divided your big project into smallers ones (because it is too big)?
If yes, you must do the same in Redmine.
You can make a global project and multiple sub-projects in Redmine (in "Settings" tab of a project in Redmine), and so, link each subproject to each repository. You can then link a repository-commit to a redmine-issue.

Comment: By Multiple repositories, I mean I have atleast two projects set up in the same project.

Comment: yes I can link repository-commit to a redmine-issue across different projects but issue doesn't show the details about the 'Associated Revisions' like in the case of repository and issue being in the same project